# Creating a VIEW in mysql

Tags: mysql, view

I would like to create a view from the following table. This table contains many many records and my goal is to have a view hold certain TOTALS (sums) for Column A and Column B but based on different WHERE clauses. Currently I have created two separate views to keep track of the sums that I need.

**My question is if I can do this in one view as opposed to two separate views.**

TABLE:  USERID  TIME  COLUMN A  COLUMN B

I want to keep track of the following two totals:

TOTAL 1: SELECT USERID, SUM(TIME) FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN A <> 0
TOTAL 2: SELECT USERID, SUM(TIME) FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN B <> 0

Is there a way to get these 2 totals in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT USERID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN_A<>0 THEN TIME ELSE 0 END) AS ColumnASum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN_B<>0 THEN TIME ELSE 0 END) AS ColumnBSum
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY USERID
```

Comment: That is great info. I was not aware of building queries like this! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Views in MySQL cannot contain multiple queries but it doesn't sound like you necessarily need a view. Why not just do

```
SELECT USERID, SUM(TIME) FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN A <> 0
UNION
SELECT USERID, SUM(TIME) FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN B <> 0
```

Is that not giving you what you need?

Comment: the union doesn't seem to work in my case because only one column heading will be created for time (and I need the two seperate time totals.

Comment: you could probably JOIN those two queries in that case ON A.USERID = B.USERID but it seems that the solution posted by Joe is doing what you need as well